The file that can't delete from cmd
I have a file which name is Immersive Control Panel.lnk. This file is shortcut of windows control panel. Here is the location where is linking of shortcut %windir%\System32\Control.exe . I need to delete this file from CMD or powershell but I can't delete. If I try right click than delete It works.
Right click and delete than delete from recyle bin is working but this method not usefull for me and this is the only method which works.
Shift + del not working. It looks working but If I refresh folder the file come back again. 12
Cmd del "Immersive Control panel" Nothing happens. There is no error.
If I change target path of this shortcut file. I can delete every method.
Here is the .lnk file what is inside.
LF7@%windir%\ImmersiveControlPanel\systemsettings.exe,-651%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%1%windir%\ImmersiveControlPanel\systemsettings.exe    -1SPSXFL8C&ma1SPS0%G`E
ms-resource:ShortItemName?1SPSMi<D*T   
1Images\Logo.pngQ3Ims-resource:TileDisplayName=Images\TileSmall.png9Images\TinyTile.pngq1SPSOYMGmU!ms-resource:PublisherDisplayNameR1SPSU(Ly9K-Twindows.immersivecontrolpanel_cw5n1h2txyewy!microsoft.windows.immersivecontrolpanelQ%windir%\ImmersiveControlPaneli,windows.immersivecontrolpanel_cw5n1h2txyewyHwindows.immersivecontrolpanel_10.0.2.1000_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy-1SPSw
lE[([8%windir%\System32\Control.exe%windir%\System32\Control.exe


Did you try to specify the .lnk extension after the shortcut name?  Try del "Immersive Control Panel.lnk"

@Jackdaw Yes I did. I did rmdir too. With del command there is no error but nothing happens otherside rmdir command the output is the file is not empty.

What is your Windows version? Are you using a Virtual Machine or a desktop computer?

This issue about my workstation pc. Buıt only 5 pc have same issue. Other 40 pc hasn't. All computers windows version are same.

If you are using the same user on all computers, I suppose some policies were applied on the computer that restrict what you trying to perform. The strangest thing is that as you wrote "Nothing happens. There is no error". Perhaps this folder containing the shortcut under the OneDrive control?

This question is similar to: deleting file through CMD. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

No my main problem is I cant delete a shortcut from cmd. I need to delete because the antivirus trying to delete after search the file but antivirus will be buggy. The file hasn't got a malware I'm pretty sure about this. @DrMoishePippik

Do you have a leading or trailing space in the filename.  Since windows fonts are proportional, leading spaces are difficult to spot in filenames.  Trailing spaces are even harder.

@cup I tried with different file names but the result is same. (without spaces)

Are you deleting as a normal user or through an elevated cmd prompt?  Even if you are admin, you need to open an elevated cmd prompt.

"No my main problem is I cant delete a shortcut from cmd. I need to delete because the antivirus trying to delete after search the file but antivirus will be buggy." Are you saying you need to delete it because you're using a non-standard, buggy, antivirus on Windows?? Why use it? Windows comes with free Defender antivirus, which is about as good as any third-party product. And the Immersive Control Panel is very useful, so why delete a shortcut to it?

Its an enterprise antivirus. Important for us. I don't want to delete shortcut actually. Before scan, AV copy files to spesific folder than try to delete after scan but It cant delete only this shortcut. Than I try to make same thing manually. I copy the control panel to desktop than run del command from cmd but nothing happened. @DrMoishePippik

I solved the problem.
If other processes are using this file than del command cant delete it. I tried to find which processes are using than I use hex editor to find dependencies.
*windows.immersivecontrolpanel_cw5n1h2txyewy!microsoft.windows.immersivecontrolpanel
%windir%\ImmersiveControlPanel
windows.immersivecontrolpanel_cw5n1h2txyewy
windows.immersivecontrolpanel_10.0.2.1000_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy*

I caught these handles from process explorer than I couldn't kill processes which are using these handles. Than I repaired my OS from ISO.
Windows handle fixing
